# Problem with Grids,Alignment

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, alignment, pixel-grid

I noticed something strange with Photoshop...I have an object and I want to align it lets say at X position: 1280! I set exactly that number and then all of a sudden it becomes 1280.50 px! I know .5 pixel isn't that a problem but then .5 and so on it will become 1px and the 1px 1,5 etc. I want something to perfectly aligned with something else!

For example, I have to objects 355x355 and one 490x490 which are both perfect circles and want them to be center aligned! but then I see that there is a difference of 1 pixel between them! How can I fix this?

I have the same issue with Illustrator and in Preferences I have set the 1 px increment!

[image: See the 1px difference?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the value 355 to 354 or 356 and you will find the perfect alignment.
You always need to have even values. Bye[image]

Comment: He said 1280. It's an even number. Bye.

Comment: yeah that solved the problem with the dimensions of each circle and it makes totally sence he's right. I'm still struggling with the position X and Y